# Cordova run android error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to run my cordova project but I have this error:

> cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V6
>       cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Proyecto\pawpals1\platforms\android\build.gradle
>       cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Proyecto\pawpals1\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\pawpals-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
>       ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\sdk
>       JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_231
>       Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
>               at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
>               at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
>               at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
>               at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
>       cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
>               at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
>               at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
>               at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
>               at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWr

I've checked environment variables and gradle is installed. I've also removed the platform and added again, I've remove the folder .gradle from C:/users/admin but is not working yet, and I've changed the java version from 1.5 to 1.8 because I had errors related with that.
I don't know what to do.